# Tkinter/Zelle - Can I send an argument into a Tkinter Motion event?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, drawing, zelle-graphics

I am working on creating a drawing program.  Presently I can DRAG and DRAW in a rectangle. While outside of the rectangle, I want to create several colours boxes to select different colours and send that colour into this Tkinter function :

```
win.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion)
```

The issue is that I am unsure how to do it.  When I try to send the "colour" into the motion event, I get an error because I am unsure how to send an additional argument into it.

```
from graphics import *
import time
win = GraphWin("mouse", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)
rect=Rectangle(Point(20,20), Point(200,300))
rect.draw(win)

def motion(event): # how can I enter another argument?
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    if (x1>20 and x1<200) and (y1>20 and y1<300):
        point1 = Point(x1, y1)
        point1.setFill("blue") # want to send a value into here
        point1.draw(win)
    else:
        pass

def drawingit():
    coord = win.checkMouse()
    if coord == None:
        print("nothing clicked")
    elif (coord.getX()>20 and coord.getX()<200) and (coord.getY()>20 and coord.getY()<300):
        win.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion)
    else:
        point1 = Point(coord.getX(), coord.getY())
        point1.setFill("red")
        point1.draw(win)
        time.sleep(.04)

while True:
    drawingit()

win.mainloop()
```

EDIT : added green colour rectangle

```
from graphics import *
import time
win = GraphWin("mouse", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)
rect=Rectangle(Point(20,20), Point(200,300))
rect.draw(win)
rectorange=Rectangle(Point(20,430), Point(200,460))
rectorange.setFill("green")
rectorange.draw(win)
pick_colour="black"

def motion(event):
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    if (x1>20 and x1<200) and (y1>20 and y1<300):
        point1 = Point(x1, y1)
        point1.setFill(pick_colour)
        point1.draw(win)
    else:
        pass

def drawingit():

    coord = win.checkMouse()
    if coord == None:
        print("nothing clicked")
        #time.sleep(0.5)
    elif (coord.getX()>20 and coord.getX()<200) and (coord.getY()>20 and coord.getY()<300):
        win.bind('<B1-Motion>',  motion)
    elif (coord.getX()>20 and coord.getX()<200) and (coord.getY()>430 and coord.getY()<460):
        pick_colour="green"
    else:
        point1 = Point(coord.getX(), coord.getY())
        point1.setFill("black")
        point1.draw(win)
        time.sleep(.04)

while True:
    drawingit()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, there are ways to send extra arguments to event handler functions. What is the source of the value of this color argument you want to send the motion event handler?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that question - so I will try to explain.  If the user clicks on a green rectangle, then I will send in the colour green.  The  value will come from the drawingit() function with a conditional statement that has the bounding box for the different colour swatches that the user can pick from.  Is that what you are asking?  It will be similar to a paint program.

Comment: There's no green rectangle in your code, nor code to handle clicking on it — so no source of the value to send the event handler. I think you need to provide a more complete [mre].

Comment: You need to add `global pick_colour` at the beginning of `drawingit()`, otherwise it will only update a local variable `pick_colour` instead of the global one.  BTW, using while loop in a tkinter application is not recommended.  Use `.after()` instead.

Comment: So the .after is a time function, right?  I did notice that using a while loop and the mouse binding function did not work.  I was hoping the method I have been using was a work-around for that.  Are you saying my method above could pose issues?

Comment: Since you have used Zelle's `graphics.py` which is based on tkinter, and `update()` is called inside `getMouse()`, so using while loop may not cause issue.  However `win.mainloop()` is not necessary for this case because the while loop is doing its job.

Comment: OK, I am not sure getMouse though.  I am using checkMouse() - does that update as well?  Yes I can see the mainloop() wouldn't do anything as it never gets to it.

Comment: It is my typo, it should be `checkMouse()` which also called `update()` inside it.

Comment: netrate: When I run the code in your EDIT (with a `global pick_colour` in the `drawingit()` function and without that `win.mainloop()` at the very end) things seem to work — so your question has been answered, correct?

Comment: I was still wondering how to send extra arguments into the : win.bind('<B1-Motion>',  motion) for future use.  The program does now work with the use of global, but I am still wondering about the arguments.

Comment: Try `win.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e: motion(e, pick_colour))`. Of course you need to change the definition of `motion()` to accept the extra argument.

Comment: Awesome!  I figured it was lambda, I just couldn't figure out how to get it to work.  Thank you acw1668!

Comment: how do I check this as solved?

Comment: @netrate you may ask acw1668 to put it as answer (below) and then you can mark answer as accepted. Or you can create answer (below) and also mark answer as accepted.